# How to graph rolling average dated-expenses per category?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

#### Goal

I have data that represent expenses, with date and category, and I want to plot the **rolling average per category over time**

---

#### Sources

I have tried using and combining the following without success

- [Python Pandas: Calculate moving average within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339021/python-pandas-calculate-moving-average-within-group) doesn't handle dates
- [Calculating monthly aggregate of expenses with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914445/calculating-monthly-aggregate-of-expenses-with-pandas) doesn't handle rolling average

---

#### Tries and MCVE

The best I've come with, using the second link is this

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randrange, seed
from datetime import datetime

seed(321)

nb = 24
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [datetime(2023, 1 + i // 2, 5) for i in range(nb)],
    "category": [item for _ in range(nb // 2) for item in ["food", "wear"]],
    "value": [randrange(10, 120) for _ in range(nb)],
})

df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

all_s = []
for x in set(df["category"]):
    s = df.loc[df['category'] == x, "value"]
    s = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="ME")).sum()
    all_s.append(s.rename(x))

df = pd.concat(all_s, axis=1).fillna(0).asfreq("ME", fill_value=0)

df.plot(style='.-', figsize=(15, 20), ylim=(0, 130))
plt.show()
```

Rendering in

[image]

---

#### Expectation

I expect to add something like a `.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)` somewhere, to get kind of a flat line on the graph, to avoid peaks and just have an average over a given period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to get the average of the rolling window calculations:

```
df = df.rolling(window=3).mean()
```

For your example, this will result in this dataframe:

```
                 wear       food
date                            
2023-01-31        NaN        NaN
2023-02-28        NaN        NaN
2023-03-31  61.000000  50.666667
2023-04-30  75.000000  53.333333
2023-05-31  85.000000  58.333333
2023-06-30  84.333333  54.000000
2023-07-31  82.000000  72.333333
2023-08-31  75.666667  80.000000
2023-09-30  58.000000  70.000000
2023-10-31  51.333333  69.666667
2023-11-30  50.333333  62.333333
2023-12-31  66.333333  54.333333
```

And this plot:
[image: rolling average plot]